# merging two queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of recipes, and I want to show a weekly value for each of them. The values are votes cast for them. My problem is that I want to make an excel-like table with all available fridays on my db, add a column for each recipe, and put it's value for the friday on that column, if any value exists.

Now apparently the easiest join doesn't work so I wrote two queries: one to get all ids for my recipes and one for the values to show. The first (MySql) query is just a select id from recipes, the second is like this:

```
select d.date,perc from 
    (SELECT date FROM weekly where YEAR(date)=2014 group by date) as d      
left join weekly on d.date = weekly.date and weekly.id_rec= :idrec
```

Any idea how to merge those two queries? Running two queries makes everything slow down, but when I tried to merge them I didn't get the correct results.

Data:
[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7d12/4)

The result should be something like:

```
Dates  |  Recipe A | Recipe B | ...
Date 1 |  0.005    | 0.11     |
Date 2 |  0        |  0       |
Date 3 |  0        |  0.1     |
```

Note that Date 2 doesn't exist for Recipe A and B, but for some other do.

Comment: Please provide on your question the tables structure. It will be a plus if you show some data sample and perfect if with all that you provide the desired result. :)

Comment: also `remove the PHP tag` in the question, it's irrelevant, question has not any PHP code or any PHP related problem

Comment: Are you trying to make join on a single table?

Comment: @Alexey Generalov yes i was

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to merge the two queries like this:

```
SELECT recipes.id, votes.date, votes.perc FROM recipes
RIGHT JOIN
(select weekly.id_rec, d.date, perc from 
    (SELECT weekly.id_rec, date FROM weekly where YEAR(date) = 2014 group by date) as d left join weekly on d.date = weekly.date) as votes 
ON votes.id_rec = recipes.id
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7d12/6)

Comment: I'm probably doing something wrong, because I can't use your query with my fiddle data. Also while your joins seems 100% ok, I did something similar but got bogus values.

Comment: I changed my answer, you needed also weekly.id_rec on the select clause of the right joined table. Added also SQL Fiddle.